# Accessing Contacts in Phonebook for SMS Message?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, sms, android-contacts

So my I've got my SMS messaging class working. However, I would like that when the user clicks on the edittext for entering the phone number...the phonebook of the phone loads and the user can select one or many contacts from there and the SMS will go to all the selected contacts. How do I load and select the contacts using the phonebook for my SMS?

I am bit stuck could I get an explanation please :)

Class:

```
    Button btnSendSMS;
    EditText txtPhoneNo;
    EditText txtMessage;

  private static final int ACTION_PICK_CONTACT=1;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_send_sms);
        btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
        txtPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhoneNo);
        txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);

        txtPhoneNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, ACTION_PICK_CONTACT);
          }
        });


        btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                String phoneNo = txtPhoneNo.getText().toString();
                String message = txtMessage.getText().toString() + displayLocation();
                displayLocation();

                if (phoneNo.length()>0 && message.length()>0)
                    sendSMS(phoneNo, message);
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                            "Please enter both phone number and message.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    }


    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resCode, data);

        switch (reqCode) {
            case (ACTION_PICK_CONTACT) :
                if (resCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                    Uri contact = data.getData();
                    Cursor cursor =  managedQuery(contact, null, null, null, null);
                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        String contact_id =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                        Cursor phoneCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contact_id,
                                null, null);
                        phoneCursor.moveToFirst();
                        String phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex("data1")); //THE NUMBER TO SEND YOUR SMS
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private String displayLocation(){
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, new LocationListener(){
                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {}
                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {}
                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {}
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {}
            });
            Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);
            double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
            double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
           return "https://www.google.co.id/maps/@"+latitude+","+longitude;
    }





    //---sends a SMS message to another device---
    private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
    {

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, Home.class), 0);
            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);


        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                new Intent(SENT), 0);

        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

        //---when the SMS has been sent---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

        //---when the SMS has been delivered---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

        android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager smms = android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager.getDefault();
        smms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
    }
```

Comment: Use `new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI)'

Comment: @itechevo...I've tried your bit like this:  txtPhoneNo.setOnClickListener(onNewIntent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI)); and have the implement method returning null. Still doesn't seem to work? Could you please elaborate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
int ACTION_PICK_CONTACT=1;

//Call this in your onclick event
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(i, ACTION_PICK_CONTACT);

//This is called when user has selected a contact
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

   switch (reqCode) {
     case (ACTION_PICK_CONTACT) :
        if (resCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

          Uri contact = data.getData();
          Cursor cursor =  managedQuery(contact, null, null, null, null);
          if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            String contact_id =cursor.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

            Cursor phoneCursor = getContentResolver().query( 
                   ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null, 
                   ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contact_id, 
                   null, null);
            phoneCursor.moveToFirst();
            String phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex("data1")); //THE NUMBER TO SEND YOUR SMS
            txtPhoneNo.setText(phoneNumber);
          }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @itechevo...I've edited my code using yours, made few changes cause was getting errors. It loads the phonebook but when I click a user it doesn't appear in the edit text with the number? Why is not storing?

Comment: Are you setting the edit text box with the number you extracted from onActivityResult?

Comment: @itechevo...I don't have a String phoneNumber, and tried to just reference the txtPhoneNo but that doesn't work, so what should i do? I believe its the last line thats holding it all back?

Comment: Try `txtPhoneNo.setText(phoneNumber)` after `String phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));`

Comment: @itechevo...Thanks man really appreciate it...Just how do I have more than one selection? Like choosing multiple contacts?

Comment: With Intent.ACTION_PICK, you can only pick one at a time. If you want to have multiple pick, you need to create your own custom list view of contacts. [Lite View Example](https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html)